# Keep returning error when trying to install MySQL-python on mac

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I've tried `sudo pip install MySQL-python`
I have python 3 and python 2 on my Mac 10.14

and I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-00klz8kk/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-00klz8kk/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-98ox2mo0
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-00klz8kk/mysql-python/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-00klz8kk/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-00klz8kk/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html, and you're using python3.8,  it seems as if ```pip install mysql-python``` uses the python3 pip.  This means, you'll need to use python2's pip (I'm guessing ```pip2```?)

Comment: further suggestion..  you could also try ```pymysql```

Answer (score 0):

try installing the following which are the same,

```
pip install pymysql
pip install mysql-connector
pip intsall mysql-connector-python
```